# Run gremlin queries outside gremlin shell

Tags: gremlin

I want to run gremlin query without logging into gremlin shell or being in docker. Is there any command or a way to execute gremlin queries without logging into gremlin shell or being in docker.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to a particular product or the gremlin console ? Check the gremlin server and how you can connect to it using HTTP API's http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.0.1-incubating/#gremlin-server

Comment: Before running "$ bin/gremlin.sh" command, i need to get the count in gremlin. May be using groovy script or is there any other way to run the gremlin queries without logging into gremlin shell (gremlin>)

Comment: Have you looked into the gremlin server? I'm not sure about your use case, but the gremlin server is what a lot of developers use to run gremlin queries from their favorite programming languages or tools